# How to DELETE something that I am SELECTING in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, mysql-workbench

I have a *SELECT* statement, and I want to *DELETE* what I am selecting. When I change the *SELECT* to a *DELETE*, I get errors. How do I use the *DELETE* to delete what I selected?

This is my query:

```
SELECT course.course_id FROM course LEFT JOIN section ON section.course_id = course.course_id WHERE section.course_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: What is the select query that you're using? Deleting should be in the format of `DELETE table WHERE ...`. Ensure that you're not doing something like `DELETE * FROM table WHERE ...`

Comment: This is my query:                                                                                    SELECT course.course_id FROM course
LEFT JOIN section ON section.course_id = course.course_id
WHERE section.course_id IS NULL;

Answer (score 4):

The DELETE keyword is used to delete an entire record. If I understand you correctly you are taking a SELECT {column} and trying to delete that column. If you want to clear the value in that specific cell use an UPDATE query.

update

I tried recreating your model
course table

```
course_id     course_name
1             First Course
2             Second Course
3             Third Course
```

section table

```
section_id    course_id    section_name
1             1            First Section
2             1            Second Section
3             3            Third Section
```

the delete query I used was

```
DELETE
FROM course
WHERE course.course_id NOT IN( SELECT section.course_id FROM section );
```

Comment: I guess I'm selecting a specific column element but I need to delete that whole row.

Comment: Exactly, glad to be of assistance!

Comment: Thank you! But when I do this, it selects the correct row, but how do I delete it now?SELECT * FROM course WHERE course_id = (SELECT course.course_id FROM course
LEFT JOIN section ON section.course_id = course.course_id
WHERE section.course_id IS NULL);

Comment: I tried this but it said "You can't specify target table 'course' for update in FROM clause":               DELETE FROM course WHERE course_id = (SELECT course.course_id FROM course
LEFT JOIN section ON section.course_id = course.course_id
WHERE section.course_id IS NULL);

Comment: Replace the initial 'SELECT *' with 'DELETE'

Comment: I don't quite understand your need for the subquery. I only see 2 tables 'course' and 'section' if I understand your query I would try 'DELETE FROM course INNER JOIN section ON section.course_id = course.course_id WHERE section.course_id IS NULL;'

Comment: Come to think of it, it won't INNER JOIN due to the fact that courae_id is null

Comment: You would need a LEFT JOIN WHERE section.course_id IS NULL

Comment: @JoshDombal i updated my initial answer with the query i used in the model i used to try to replicate your model. hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `delete` keyword. The syntax for this is usually along the lines of:

```
delete from table_name
where ...
```

The `...` in my example should match exactly what you have in your select statement.

You can find more info on this in my MySQL [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html).

Answer (score 0):

The `DELETE` statement has a `WHERE` clause. Use the `WHERE` clause of the `SELECT` statement as the `WHERE` clause for the `DELETE` statement.

for instance:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE id = 1;
```

will have the following as its delete

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id = 1;
```

in case your select has no `WHERE` clause;

```
SELECT name FROM table;
```

the statement becomes:

```
DELETE FROM table;
```

The `WHERE` clause of the `SELECT` statement is the same as the `WHERE` clause for the `DELETE` statement.

**NB:** The second example will require that safe mode is disabled.